# BibLatex not showing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Even though I read other posts about this problem, I've not found the answer, so if anyone can point out what am I doing wrong, it would be great!

This is my preambule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand\eref[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{dokumentacija.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

And here is dokumentacija.bib file:

```
@article{GeBeKr01,
author =  "Georghiades, A.S. and Belhumeur, P.N. and Kriegman, D.J.",
title =   "From Few to Many: Illumination Cone Models for Face Recognition under
           Variable Lighting and Pose",
journal = "IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intelligence",
year =  2001,
volume = 23,
number = 6,
pages= "643-660"}

@article{KCLee05,
author =  "K.C. Lee and J. Ho and D. Kriegman",
title =   "Acquiring Linear Subspaces for Face Recognition under Variable Lighting ",
journal = "IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intelligence",
year =  2005,
volume = 27,
number = 5,
pages= "684-698"}

@article{KarRan,
author =  "Karen Braman, Randy C. Hoover",
title =   "Facial Recognition Using Tensor-Tensor Decompositions",
journal = "SIAM Journal on Imaging Sciences 6",
year = 2013, 
pages= "26"}

@book{SteNath,
author =  "Steven L. Brunton, J. Nathan Kutz",
title =   "Data Driven Science & EngineeringMachine Learning, Dynamical Systems, and Control",
year =  2017,
pages= "572"}
```

And i added:

```
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The entry `KarRan` has two issues: (1) Regardless of the desired format in the output, multiple names *must* be separated with `and` in the input. `author = "Steven L. Brunton, J. Nathan Kutz",` is incorrect and should be `author = "Steven L. Brunton and J. Nathan Kutz",`. (2) `&` is a special symbol for LaTeX. If you want to print a `&` you must escape it to `\&`. So `title = "Data Driven Science & EngineeringMachine Learning, Dynamical Systems, and Control",` is wrong and should be `title = "Data Driven Science \& Engineering Machine Learning, Dynamical Systems, and Control",`.

Comment: Next to the "Recompile" button there should be a little icon. If there are any errors or warnings reported that button should show a number. Click on it to check all errors and warnings. You *must* remove all errors before you can expect to get usable output from LaTeX. Focus on the errors first and tackle them one by one starting from the topmost error.

Answer (score 1):

It will only show once you have cited anything. It works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand\eref[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{dokumentacija.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

        test Citations: \cite{GeBeKr01}\cite{KarRan}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Which editor are you using? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I'm using Overleaf. No errors, only warning about empty bibliography on input line...

Comment: is your .bib-file in the same folder as your .tex-file? it works fine for me in Overleaf... maybe try using \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} ? You will also get the empty bibliography error if there are no citations in your document from the bib.file. Have you already cited something?